# Error with the Python Fuel SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, fuel-sdk, python

I am trying to return all the data extensions within my org, and within the same script return a list from all the columns by looping through the results of from step 1.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import ET_Client

try:
    debug = False
    stubObj = ET_Client.ET_Client(False, debug)


    # Get all of the DataExtensions in an Account - This works
    print('>>> Get all of the DataExtensions in an Account')
    de = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension()
    de.auth_stub = stubObj
    de.props = ["CustomerKey"]
    de.search_filter = {'Property' : 'IsSendable','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : 'True'}
    getResponse = de.get()
    #de.search_filter = {'Property' : 'IsSendable','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : 'True'}


    extract = getResponse.results

    list2 = []

    for item in extract:
        list2.append(item[2])


    print(list2)

    # list2 now has all my customers keys , which I pass to a Second API Call
    for x in list2:
        de_columns = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension_Column()
        de_columns.props = ["CustomerKey"]
        de_columns.search_filter = {'Property' : 'CustomerKey','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : x}
        getResponse2 = de_columns.get()
        print(getResponse2.results)

except Exception as e:
    print('Caught exception: ' + str(e.message))
    print(e)
```

It works until I try looping the results of the second API and I get this error:

> File "GetAllDEs.py", line 45, in 
>       getResponse2 = de_columns.get()   File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/FuelSDK/objects.py", line 234,
>   in get
>       obj = ET_Get(self.auth_stub, self.obj, self.props, self.search_filter)                         File
>   "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/FuelSDK/rest.py", line 145, in
>   **init**
>       auth_stub.refresh_token() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'refresh_token'

Not sure where to go from here. I will appreciate any pointers on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's Django management command script that queries data extensions and their columns.  You can remove the Django parts.  Perhaps your column search filter should use the 'like' operator instead of 'equals'.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from FuelSDK import ET_Client, ET_DataExtension, ET_DataExtension_Column

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Queries data extensions (including columns) per Business Unit from Marketing Cloud'
    client_id = 'xxxx'
    clientsecret = 'xxxxx'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        pass

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            stub_obj = ET_Client(False, False, params={'clientid': client_id,
                                                   'clientsecret': client_secret})
            de = ET_DataExtension()
            de.auth_stub = stub_obj
            de.props = ["CustomerKey","Name"]
            de.search_filter = {'Property': 'Name', 'SimpleOperator': 'like', 'Value': 'test'}
            de_res = de.get()

            de_list = []
            for ext in de_res.results:
                de_list.append(ext.CustomerKey)

            # query for the columns
            for x in de_list:
                stub_obj = ET_Client(False, False, params={
                                     'clientid': client_id,
                                     'clientsecret': client_secret})
                de_col_req = ET_DataExtension_Column()
                de_col_req.auth_stub = stub_obj
                de_col_req.props = ["CustomerKey"]
                de_col_req.search_filter = {'Property': 'CustomerKey',
                                        'SimpleOperator': 'like',
                                        'Value': x}
                de_col_res = de_col_req.get()
                de_cols_added = []
                for res_item in de_col_res.results:
                    print(res_item)

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e.message))
            print(e)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, Can you share your script? what version of python are you using because this fix doesnt seem to be working for me.

Comment: Sure thing.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've also created a GitHub gist file here: https://gist.github.com/mshamma/df502e569d87876b8a0c0d35e36632f5